# Adding new In a Cart Session

Tags: php, mysql, session

Am trying to add an array of products in my session but all the code does is to replace my current product please help me to find this mistake. When i click the button the product in the session changes to the one i have just entered any suggestions . here is my code below.

```
<?php

require_once("../../init.php");

    function runQuery($query){
        $result = $db->query($query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }       
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }

if(!empty($_GET["action"])) {
switch($_GET["action"]) {
    case "add":
        if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
            $productByCode = mysqli_fetch_array($db->query("SELECT * FROM productpurchase WHERE productname='" . $_GET["productname"] . "'"));

            $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["productname"]=>array('productname'=>$_POST["productname"],  'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'sell'=>$_POST["price"]));

            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                if(in_array($productByCode[0]["productname"],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                            if($productByCode[0]["productname"] == $k)
                                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["quantity"];
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
            }
        }
    break;
    case "remove":
        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                    if($_GET["productname"] == $k)
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);              
                    if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
            }
        }
    break;
    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
    break;  
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Edited my answer to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your product wrong way. Since product name is `key` in `array`, you should add it like this.

```
$productName = $productByCode[0]["productname"];
$itemArray = array('productname' => $productName, 'quantity' => $_POST["quantity"], 'sell' => $_POST["price"]);
$_SESSION["cart_item"][$productName] = $itemArray;
```

Also your `in_array` `if` statement will fail every time, since cart `array` values are `arrays` and you are comparing against `string`. Use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get `array` of product names.

Change it to

```
if(in_array($productName, array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
```

And you don't need `foreach` loop.

Final code would be

```
<?php

// Add product name to variable, since we will use it often
// This would be key in cart array.
$productName = $productByCode[0]["productname"];

// Array with product data
$itemArray = array('productname' => $productName, 'quantity' => $_POST["quantity"], 'sell' => $_POST["price"]);

// Check if cart has some products already
if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {

  // Is product already in cart? If so, edit only quantity
  if(in_array($productName, array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
    $_SESSION["cart_item"][$productName]["quantity"] = $_POST["quantity"];
  } else {
    // Product is not in cart, but we have other products in cart.
    // So just add to existing cart array.
    $_SESSION["cart_item"][$productName] = $itemArray;
  }
}
else {
    // No products, create cart session and add first product
    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array();
    $_SESSION["cart_item"][$productName] = $itemArray;
}

?>
```

Comment: try what @Rene Kors has said. this should work fine.

Comment: Rene Kors Thanks Man this make sense. @James Njuguna Thegio mani wacha nijaribu

Comment: @mbaula ni wega daddy